# DataGridView bound to a Dictionary and updated with a thread

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures

I have a Dictionary bound to DataGridView by using following sample code.

[DataGridView bound to a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary)

**Please see the above question first**

The diffrence is that i am updating dictionary from a thread. (Event handler of another class).

My Event handler is as below

```
static void f_PriceChanged(Objet f, eventData e)
{

    if (prices.ContainsKey(e.ItemText))
        prices[e.ItemText] = e.price;
    else
        prices.Add(e.ItemText, e.price);

}
```

Not to mention the prices is declared as class level.

I have modified the button code from original post as

```
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
    btn.Click += delegate
    {                
        bl.Reset();
    };
    form.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Internally the Dictionary is updated as expected but grid does not update. Clicking on button generate exception

***Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute***

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a lock statement to protect your shared resource : the dictionary.

```
private object _lock = new object();

private void Reset()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}

void f_PriceChanged(Objet f, eventData e)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        if (prices.ContainsKey(e.ItemText))
            prices[e.ItemText] = e.price;
        else
            prices.Add(e.ItemText, e.price);
    }

}
```

You'll have to make `f_PriceChanged()` a member.