# DataGridView bound to custom class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I used this thread's answer to bind a DataGridView to a dictionary:

[DataGridView bound to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary)

This works fine if I use `Dictionary<string, double>`, but if I use a class instead of string (`Dictionary<MyClass, double>`) the DataGridView displays the string representation of MyClass. MyClass has a string property (Value) that I would like to be displayed in the DataGridViwe column. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to implement `ToString()` in your class, if this is an option, eg:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    // ...
}
```