# How to bind a dictionary object to a Windows Forms gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

How can I bind a dictionary object to a datagridview in Windows Forms?

```
 Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 result.Add(arrFilename[i].fileName,"Found");
 dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

The dataview grid doesn't bind. What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView.DataSource` needs an object that implements `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList`, or `IBindingListView`.

Since none of `Dictionary`, `Dictionary.ValueCollection` or `Dictionary.KeyCollection` implements it, you can't bind directly to it.

If you just want a readonly list of values you could add them to a `List` and bind to that, for example (assuming your dictionary uses int and string as the key and value types):

```
List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
list.AddRange( myDict.Values);

DataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

If you want to do anything more clever then the easiest solution is to not use a `Dictionary` as your data structure. You could potentially subclass your `Dictionary` and implement one of the bindable interfaces, but that's probably more effort and complication than necessary.

See *[DataGridView bound to a generic dictionary](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d3698481-0b48-4b09-8652-5bfa35a13585/)* by Rory (MSDN forum).

Answer (score 1):

It's not straightforward as the dictionary object doesn't implement the IList interface that the datagridview expects sources to adhere to.

This might help:

[DataGridView bound to a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Dictionary. Instead use an array of DictionaryEntry.
I think because each item in dictionary List hasn't a known type.

It shows no error, but if you set a combobox datasource to a dictionary it says 
it doesn't implement `IList`.