# Binding a DataGridView to a 2 Dimensional Collection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

"*Every few months I write something in WinForms to remind myself why I hate it*" (quote from another op)
I thought that this would be pretty straightforward, but I am lamely failing into coming up with some working code.

I just want to bind a DataGridView to "ANY" convenient 2-Dimensional List/Collection/Banana,
**AND** update that collection at high frequency by **Efficiently** (performance, latency) accessing the first dimension as *the Key* to update the 2nd dimension as *the Data*. Ideally I needed a Dictionary but it is not "bindable" *per se*.
Needless to say any change on the binded collection should display on the DGV.

A generalization of the 2 dimensions to N dimensions would be appreciable, as long as I can efficiently acces a "key" on the collection to update the row.

**Issue example**

```
var g = this.dataGridView1;
var s = new Dictionary<string, string>();
s.Add("1", "Test1");
s.Add("2", "Test2");
s.Add("3", "Test3");
g.DataSource = s.ToArray();
```

The problem here is that the toArray() conversion makes the dgv bound to an array and not to the actual dictionary. Therefore any change on the dic won't be reported on the dgv.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you are going to have to implement ITypedList and create a custom PropertyDescriptor representing each column (usually keeping the "key" or "index" as a field in the descriptor). Then override the GetValue and SetValue to fetch the values from your collection.

I have an example of a transposer that might be useful to set the context - will see if I can find it.

For 2-way notification you will nee to implement IBindingList, and the list-change events.

Comment: Hey Marc :-) I am struggling to use this example of yours, thought it would help me fix the issue but I guess I missed something : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary

Comment: @Mika that was a while ago, but that would provide only 1-way binding; a full 2-way binding model would be significantly more complex.

Comment: Yeah That's what I noticed reading/using the code. Jeez... We're in 2011 good Lord... Seems Like everybody has to reinvent the Wheel !! Oh Well...

Comment: @Mika here that transpose example; a dictionary would not be hugely different: https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/ae1251a6855b9254/29ed401fdfb1b4c1?lnk=gst&q=transpose+propertydescriptor&hl=en&pli=1

Comment: @Mika note: I'm not at a pc at the moment, so can't really hack that together - I could probably look at some point over the weekend if you are stuck.

Comment: Yeah It's a bit overkill as you stated it :-) I will stick to a plain Bindinglist + Iteration to find/update stuff. Not very sexy but if it turns out not to be satisfying in terms of performance I'll use you transpose. Many Thanks again