# In C#, How to bind a Dictionary to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (`dgv_Orders`) and a Dictionary(`orders<uint, Order>`). Class Order has the following members: `uint order_id, uint volume, double price` I would like to be able to have dgv_orders display all of the values contained in the dictionary, row by row, listing out all of their properties. I need the Dictionary structure, so that I can edit the values in O(1) time.

I have gotten this to work with a BindingList & I have also looked at the following solution..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/854969/1143465

and gotten it to almost work, except that the DataGridView just has the columns, Key & Value, whereas I would like it to show order_id, volume, & price. Are there any ways to do so?

Thanks in advance!

```
class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private uint order_id;
    private double price;
    private uint volume;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Order(uint order_id)
    {
        this.order_id = order_id;
        price = 10.0;
        volume = 1;
    }

    public uint Order_ID
    {
        get { return order_id; }
        set { order_id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Order_ID"); }
    }

    public uint Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Price"); }
    }

    public uint Volume
    {
        get { return volume; }
        set { volume = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Volume"); }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
         if(PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is to bind to the `Values` property of the dictionary.

Well, actually, that's not entirely true. You could create a new class that inherits from dictionary and then implement the IBindingList or IObservableCollection interfaces.

All of our core collection class inherit from [System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) which has similar performance characteristics as dictionary (`provides both O(1) indexed retrieval and keyed retrieval that approaches O(1)`), but is also more easily serialized over WCF and Web Services than dictionaries.

**Update**

Here is an example of a collection for your order class:

```
public class OrderCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<uint, Order>
{
    protected override uint GetKeyForItem(Order item)
    {
        return item.Order_ID;
    }
}
```

I was able to successfully test this with the following code and a new, default datagridview:

```
        var cOrders = new OrderCollection();

        cOrders.Add(new Order(1));
        cOrders.Add(new Order(2));
        cOrders.Add(new Order(3));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = cOrders;
```

Comment: you can bind to a Dictionary.. however .. what is the data source that you are using..? can you post some code..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE the data source is the dictionary, which I will be modifying through my code. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yes, you can bind to a dictionary, but the implementation of IENumerator only exposes the underlying KeyValuePair, so unless you have a simple value (i.e. string), it won't do you a tremendous amount of good.

Comment: competent_tech that's correct.. also I am not sure what the OP is exactly looking for once he binds it to a Dictionary.. perhaps he should bind his data to something like an a dataadapter of some sort.. what are your thoughts.

Comment: it's really hard to tell if something will or will not work unless Joshua post some sort of Interface or Data Structure that he has....

Comment: I have updated the answer with some additional thoughts. I think that the ObjectModel.KeyedCollection is a much better solution for this problem than Dictionary.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have added the Order class that I am using, the Dictionary object is just the c# dictionary, and the DataGridView is the normal WinForms DataGridView

Comment: @competent_tech I'm not quite understanding the benefit of switching to the KeyedCollection if I don't need to serialize the data?

Comment: @Joshua: Sorry, should have been more clear. In addition to serialization, this collection also implements IList, which returns the underlying records (i.e. the list of Orders) instead of the KeyValuePair collection that dictionary does (i.e. the list of KeyValuePair<int, Order>).

Comment: @Joshua: I just updated the answer with an implementation of the OrderCollection class and some test code that I used to verify that this will work correctly with a default datagridview.

Comment: @competent_tech Thank you, but this will only return the order_id. I would like all properties of order to be displayed, which I was able to successfully do with a BindingList of the Order objects shown above.

Comment: That's very odd; when I ran it I got every column automatically. Can you try adding an empty datagridview and assigning to that in order to see if there is a configuration in your current DGV that is preventing the columns from being displayed?

Comment: @competent_tech Sorry for the late response. It does work with a new DGV! I will try to determine what is causing my original DGV to fail. Would I go about implementing sorting the same way I have sorted the BindingList (using this: [link]http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html )

Comment: @competent_tech It works 95% of the way now, the only issue is that the DGV needs to be refreshed manually (such as minimize/maximize, moving the scrollbar over and going back). Is there a way to automatically refresh it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a starting example and change the variables to match your usecase.

```
Dictionary<string, double> someDictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
_bindingSource.DataSource = someDictionary;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it is possible to bind to a `Dictionary<T>`, but is it reasonable? The purpose of a dictionary is to lookup values form a given key, what the DataGridView will not do. A `List<T>` that allows access to individual items through an index seems more appropriate. A `List<T>` can also be sorted in a meaningful way, where as the dictionary will yield a completely 'wild' order based on hash values.