# C# List of dictionaries to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, binding, datagridview

I want to display in datagridview data from List but with All data from dictionary (or list).
I have two classes like below. And now I want to list in DataGridView all MeasureSteps from dictionary, one for one row, with multiplying informations from Board class.

What control help me? Or if I can do this with datagridview, just how?

```
class Board
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
    public string TestProgram { get; set; }
    public string TestRevision { get; set; }
    public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    public string TestTime { get; set; }
    public string TestObjectRevision { get; set; }
    public string TestObjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string TestObjectName { get; set; }
    public string InstrumentInventoryNumber { get; set; }
    public string InstrumentArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public string InstrumentName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,MeasureStep> Measurements { get; set; }
}
class MeasureStep
{
    public string TestFunction { get; set; }
    public string Descripton { get; set; }
    public double LowerLimit { get; set; }
    public double UpperLimit { get; set; }
    public double MeasuredValue { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public bool Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: would you pls take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [master-detail form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984462%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Alternatively, you can create a grid where rows (of `Board`) can expand to display its children (of `MeasureStep`s), but that would be more complex.