# How to set a new property for an array in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
Dim SteamGames As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each Game As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Me.tb_SteamDir.Text)
    SteamGames.Add(Game, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Game))
Next Game

For Each Pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In SteamGames
    dgv_Table.Rows.Add(Pair.Key)
    dgv_Table.Rows.Add(Pair.Value)
Next Pair
```

I am getting both the folder directory and the folder's name in the same column, how do I make them separate into different columns?

Comment: The word `Property` has special meaning in this context, so which `Property` are you trying to change, or what is it that you really want to do?  Do you want to change one of the *values* in the array?

Comment: I am trying to fill a table with data from an array, and right now it returns only the length of the strings in the array. What I want is to change the property of the strings in the array to the string itself so when I populate the table it displays that name of the files.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a different type for your `DataSource` - maybe a `Dictionary(Of [Key], [Value])`?  Or, is there a way to tell the `dgv_Table` how to interpret the object given in its `DataSource` property?  Your example does not show the type for the `dgv_Table` object, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Ok, so I want to display the name of the files inside a folder, that the users inputs, into a table that displays it to the user, how can I do that?

Comment: I really think you should look into using a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` as your data source.  Look around at how to populate and use that object type with a ComboBox.  There are plenty of questions already asked and answered about it.  If you run into any specific problems with that approach, feel free to come back with your additional findings.  For you, your `Key` would be the full path and your `Value` would be the folder name.

Comment: @TLS I changed the code in the question to use a dictionary and now as an output I am getting "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.String]"

Comment: Looks like you've added the `Dictionary` object as a value into a single row of the table.  You'll need to iterate through the Dictionary and add a row for each entry in it.  The table row will need to have at least 2 columns - one for the key and one for the value.

Comment: @TLS So I changed that code some more and still can't get it to work, and I tried using cell select to move to the other column but that would give me an error that said that it didn't exist but there are two columns that I have made and it wouldn't recognize the second one.

Comment: This answer to a similar question is probably what you need. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/855954/475820](http://stackoverflow.com/a/855954/475820)  I did a Google search for "populate datagridview using a dictionary .net"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should load the ComboBox and the DataGridView as you requested:

```
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    DT.Columns.Add("Full Path")
    Dim GameNames_Master As New List(Of String)
    For Each Dir As DirectoryInfo In New DirectoryInfo(Me.tb_SteamDir.Text).GetDirectories
        GameNames_Master.Add(Dir.Name)
        DT.Rows.Add(New Object() {Dir.FullName})
    Next Dir
    dgv_Table.DataSource = DT
    Me.cb_Games.DataSource = GameNames_Master
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified code. But back to my question, I am trying to fill a table with information from user input that I store in an array. But when I did that at first it just gave me the length of the strings. So I looked around a little and found out that it takes that first public property and displays that, which is length. So what I need to do is change the property of the array to the text instead of the length. I just need to know how.

Comment: That makes no sense at all sir.  Sorry.  What you could do, though, is post the actual code you have that deals with the **database** and **reproduces the problem you've described**.  The code you've posted I assumed is simply populating a ComboBox.  So post code that reproduces this: "But when I did that at first it just gave me the length of the strings."

Comment: I am so sorry, I missed a line of the code when I post the question, it is fixed now. I also changed the code so that it is using the simplified code.

Comment: Not quite, I am just using the combo box as a check to make sure that everything is displayed. I want the full directories of the things in the combo box displayed in the table.

Comment: So you want the files from **all** the directories listed in the table?

Comment: No, I don't want the files at all, I want the combo box to list the names of all of the folders in a given directory, and I want the table to show the full directory of the folders.

Like I give the program the directory "C:" and in the combo box I would get "Program Files, Program Files (x86), Users, Windows" and in the table I would get, "C:\Program Files, C:\Program Files (x86), C:\Users, C:\Windows".

Comment: Huh?  Earlier you said: "I want the full directories of the things in the combo box displayed in the table."  Now you just said: "I want the table to show the full directory of the folders."  So how does that jive with "I don't want the files at all", and your previous comment of "I want to display the name of the files inside a folder".  So confused as to what the heck you're trying to display...good night.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, but I added something at the end of the original post about what I want to make it clear. And thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Yes!...that's how to describe your requirements.  Can definitely work with that.  =)