# Datagridview bound to Dictionary in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dictionary, datagridview

I found this: [DataGridView bound to a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary/855954#855954)

One solution to bind the Datagridview to a Dictionary is the following C# code:

```
var _priceDataArray = from row in _priceData select new { Item = row.Key, Price = row.Value };
```

Now I tried this in vb.net using a C# to vb.net converter. The converter gives me the following:

```
Dim _priceDataArray = From row In _priceDataNew With { _
Key .Item = row.Key, _
Key .Price = row.Value}
```

However, this doesnt work. Error Message on the *with* statement: "end-of-statement expected"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion should be:

```vb
Dim _priceDataArray =
    From row In _priceDataNew
    Select New With {
        Key .Item = row.Key,
        Key .Price = row.Value
    }
```