# BindingList<T> equivalent for Dictionary in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, data-binding, listbox

In WinForms you can bind a Dictionary via a `BindingSource` to a ListBox

```
Dictionary<string, GraphApiFunction> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GraphApiFunction>();

listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(myDictionary, null);
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

However changes after setting the DataSource in `myDictionary` cannot be detected and thus the ListBox is not updated.
For Lists there is a special BindingSource called BindableList

```
var myBindableList = new BindingList<string>();
listBox1.DataSource = myBindableList;
```

My Question is

- is there any equivalent of `BindingList<T>` for a `Dictionary`
- or are there other ways to keep the ListBox updated (without resetting `DataSource` on every change)?

Comment: Try setting the datasource to null and then back to the binding source.  The control paint method doesn't automatically get called when changes are made and setting to null will force the paint method to run.

Comment: Could be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/854969/1997232).

Comment: Have you tried BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, GraphApiFunction>>?