# DataGridView bound to a Nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary, datagridview

I've tried seeing this: [DataGridView bound to a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary)

But it's not exactly what I'm looking for, so here I am.

I have a dictionary like this (just an example of how it looks like):

```
{
    "file": 
    {
        "var-type": 
            {
                "var1": 
                       {
                           "description": "the description here",
                           "length": "the length here",
                           "type": "the type here",
                           "line": "the line number here",
                       }
            }
    }
}
```

And would like to have a `DataGridView` (real-time, thus binding it) that looks like this:

```
+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Name |   Description   |     Length      |     Type      |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+
| var1 | the description | the length here | the type here |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

This `DataGridView` will be in a `TabPage` (inside a `TabController`, and that tab page's name is `var-type`)

At first I had a dictionary, and every time the user wanted a `DataGridView` of it, the `DataGridView` would be made again and again from zero.

So when the user changes something, they have to reopen the `DataGridView` or refresh it manually in order to see the new changes. I don't want this. So I tried having `DataTables` for each `var-type` (and using a `Dictionary` as a `DataTable` collection, and the user would get real-time changes whenever they edit something.

That worked pretty well. But when it comes to editing a specific var's information, I would have to use `.Select()` (and I can't store the line number in the same DataTable). I would like to avoid this, so I went back to a one-dictionary-for-all again. I also heard that a dictionary is much more lightweight.

I've also tried storing the line number for each variable when using `DataTables` to avoid `.Select()`, but I also have some problems with this method, and would really prefer to have a dictionary instead.

I don't want to make the `DataGridView` and use a for loop each time the user wants to see it (hence I went with DataTables as properties that I can access anywhere, and just use them as `DataSource` whenever I want to display them), I just want to be able to use them whenever I want. Is this possible?

Just for the record; yeah this is a parser. And thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I answer postings like this all the time.  It looks like you have JSON, but do not see the classes for the object (nor dictionary).  I can easily post code to turn you LIst() object into a datatable but do not presently have enough info to accomplish the task.

Comment: It's not an actual JSON, it was just an example to make it readable. It's a dictionary. I want to avoid for-looping each time, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            Dictionary<string, DataRow> dict1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> dict2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. But you seem to have misunderstood what I'm trying to do. I have said that I ditched the DataTables and now I'm using a one-for-all-dictionary. I gave an example as a JSON of how the dictionary looks like, and how I want it to be as a DataGridView. When adding something new to the dictionary, I want to change the DataGridView real-time.

Comment: Why ditch the DataTable which is more efficient then getting a JSON and then converting JSON to classes?  You should always change the DataSource of the DGV instead of trying to modify the DGV directly.

Comment: @Rookie  If you want real-type updates, you need an object that can notify property changes. A `DataTable` can, so do both `BindingSource` and `BindingList`. You're best friend here, is probably a DataTable linked to a BindingSource. Btw, you **really**  don't need a DataTable for each `var-type`, that's the DataRow content. You could add a Column (to the DataTable, hidden in the DGV) that acts as an identifier/indexer, if needed.

Comment: ...I don't have a JSON, mate. I've said it a couple of times. It was only an example, the source is an `internal static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>> Variables { get; set; }`, I'm not trying to modify the DGV directly. I just want it to update when my dictionary changes.

Comment: @Jimi: I can still have multiple tab pages each with a different `var-type` with just one DataTable?

Comment: If you bind different DGVs to the same BindingSource, all will be updated when something changes. You might have to play with the `CurrencyManager` sometimes, but that's it. Also, note that filtering a DataTable using a DataView, then using the DataView as the DataSource, the binding is still active and all updates work the same way.

Comment: @Jimi: You said I don't need a different DataTable for each var-type, how so? Each var-type has its variables, and each variable must have Name - Description - Length - Type

Comment: I'm looking at the structure you posted. A `"var-type"`, whatever that is in practice, it's an identifier. Thus a field that identifies the *owner* of a record. You're showing that the data in the DGV should be `flattened` (reduced to one record). It look quite straightforward to me. I don't see what problem you might have. I see a lot of problems coming from a nested Dictionary. Should you decide to actually use that data structure as a JSON (or like a JSON) and *deserializing* to a DataTable, all *problems* are gone.

Comment: Are you saying you have you have a dictionary for multiple files and then a 2nd level dictionary for each type like "var-type" and then a third level dictionary of properties?  You siad : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>> Variables { get; set; }

Comment: @Jimi: I think we both have a misunderstanding. Could you please provide an example of what you're talking about? All I want is to update a DGV that has a Dictionary as its DataSource when new keys get added to the dictionary. The "var-type" you're talking about is a tab page, inside that tab page is a DGV of that specific var-type. I can't have multiple var-types in one DataTable, it's not a dictionary. It's one DataTable per type, so I can do that table I posted.

Comment: @jdweng: hey, yes. :) 4 levels of dictionary nested, all date in one dictionary. Just like that JSON I posted

Comment: Do you want to update all 4 dictionaries or just one?

Comment: @jdweng: only the last two levels. If you look at that JSON, I would like to update var1 and the JSON inside it. I can already do this, but would have to refresh the DGV manually. I want it to happen automatically. Just like when the DataSource is DataTable, it happens automatically

Comment: You have to force the DGV to repaint.  It doesn't automatically repaint.  So the trick is to set the data source to null and then back to the table like : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @jdweng: how do i do that whenever the dictionary changes? the DGV is in a different form. Is DataTables really my best option here?

Comment: You need to communicate to 2nd form with DGV using the instance of the form.  Create a method in the form that sets DataSource to Null and then to table.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Hmm, okay, thanks. I think I'm going with what @Jimi said, and switch to DataTables. Thanks a lot for replying, @jdweng!

Comment: If you have some DGV2 in different Forms, remember to use a BindingSource to bind the DataTables to the DGVs. This way, all the bound DGVs will be updated (real-time), even if you show a Form as modal `[Form].ShowDialog();`.