# C# How to display a ConcurrentDictionary in a DataGridView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, concurrentdictionary

I have an object "User"

```
public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string LastRequestId { get; set; }
    }
```

In the main program I have a ConcurrentDictionary "UserList" (read/write by multiple threads)

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> UserList;
```

Is there a way to display the ConcurrentDictionary in a DataGridView?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| Username | First Name | Last Name | Last Request Id |
-------------------------------------------------------
| User_1   | John       | Smith     | REQ_000123      |
-------------------------------------------------------
| User_2   | Jane       | Doe       | REQ_000124      |
-------------------------------------------------------
| User_3   | Will       | Iam       | REQ_000125      |
-------------------------------------------------------
| User_4   | Robert     | New       | REQ_000126      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The list should display real time data

Comment: Do you have some code showing how you're setting up the DataGridView and handling changes to your dictionary?

Comment: No, how can I do so?

Comment: The `User` class seems to be mutable. Do you really need to change the values of the `UserName`, `FirstName`, `LastName` amd `LastRequestId` properties, after a `User` instance has been created and added to the dictionary?

Comment: The last request id is changing, the rest remains unchanged

Comment: Do you actually need a ConcurrentDictionary? Can't you update the UI using a standard `IProgress<T>` delegate instead? Maybe using a class that raise list / content changed events? It looks like the Key is just the ID of a User  -- Can you show the procedure that add items to this Dictionary?

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide an example of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentDictionary` doesn't support display directly in a UI because it is not an `IList` or an `IListSource`. So you will need to create an object that is representative of your Dictionary's contents that implements one of those interfaces, assign it to the `DataGridView.DataSource`, and update that list from the UI thread.

One possible approach for this is to add a `Timer` to your `Form` that fires periodically (say once a second or so), and compares the contents of your dictionary to the contents of the `DataGridView.DataSource` and synchronizes them. (Removes elements that have been removed, adds elements that have been added, etc). This approach won't scale well at all if you have lots of entries being added very quickly, but that seems unlikely.

Here's an example using a regular `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` [DataGridView bound to a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary), which describes several ways to convert a dictionary type to a `BindingList<T>`.