# Making my data object suitable for (easy) use with DataGridView and/or DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagrid

I have inherited a model object that conforms to IEnumerable, but none of the other Binding-related interfaces. The object is table-like and normally populated with data that ultimately comes from Excel. The result of reading these files is a DTable object with:

- DKeys, a Property list of ints for the row numbers - not contiguous or in order
- DRows, a dictionary with those numbers as keys and dictionaries as values
- DCell objects in the DRows, dictionaries of column name/value
- DColumns, a list containing DColumn objects - name, ordinal position, format, etc.

I am not familiar with grid controls, so I simply did:

```
    Dim BindingSource1 As New BindingSource
    BindingSource1.DataSource = TestData.Customers
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

...and this actually did something, it produced a single-column display with the Keys in the correct order. This was a bit of a surprise, I didn't think it would do anything at all. I assume it picked DKeys as that is the only Property that is IEnumerable?

The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) lacks a single document that explains how to do this, and is generally difficult to follow as there is nothing that says "this is the thing you need to do", it's just page after page of random-sounding terms. I *believe* what I need to do is implement IListSource, specifically GetData and Columns, is that the simplest solution?

I have looked at [a number of threads here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary), but most of these suggest copying the objects from your model to another object that works correctly, or using LinQ to automate that copy. I'd prefer to

So can someone give me a primer, or point to one, that shows a "simple way" to adapt my existing collection so it "just works" in a grid?

Comment: In the "Remarks" section of the HelpViewer doc for `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`, the second paragraph appears to explain exactly what you are asking about i.e. how the DataGridView generates columns from the bound source.  You may want to implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.

Comment: What Type is TestData.Customers? Is it a `List(Of Object)`?

Comment: @HardCode - it is an IDTable, which implements IEnumerable. I have since added IListSource (which was easy enough) and use GetList to populate the Grid, which also produces a list of Keys if one uses Auto. I attempted to add columns bound to fields I know are in the Row subclass, like Name, but that produces nothing, not entirely unexpected.

Comment: Are all of these D* classes custom classes? Google produced no results for them, except for IDTable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-frs1/f32d4c62-914a-44b4-a9c4-dfab8a96856b

Comment: @HardCode - yes, correct. They have no basis in the MS data related hierarchy, they are stand-alone classes.

Answer (score 1):

When data binding objects that have properties which are another object (from composition) or a collection of other objects, the DataGridView will only display the data from the parent object. If I remember correctly, it will display a value of the object Property's type in the cell, for Properties of the parent that are objects.

Let's call what you are currently trying to bind to the DGV the "Parent" object. One possibility is to create a data transfer object (DTO), where you can load this DTO with the elements of Parent that you want displayed. Consider this rudimentary example (typed from memory, untested):

```
Public Class MyAddressClass
    Public Property AddressLine1 As String
    Public Property AddressLine2 As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property State As String
    Public Property ZipCode As String
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Address As MyAddressClass
    Public Property TelephoneNumbers As List(Of String)
    Public Property CreateDate As Date
    Public Property UpdateDate As Date
End Class

' Somewhere in the code:
Dim customers As New List(Of Customer) = GetTheDataFromSomeDatabase()
```

Now, let assume you want to transform the data in `customers` to a view that will properly present only the customer data that you want in a DGV.

```
' We only want certain data elements of a customer in the DGV:
Public Class CustomerView
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property AddressLine1 As String
    Public Property AddressLine2 As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property State As String
    Public Property ZipCode As String
End Class

' Somewhere else in the code, load up a List(of CustomerView)
Dim list As New List(Of CustomerView)

' Remember, the "customers" variable was previously loaded from a database.
For Each c As Customer In customers 

    Dim cv As New CustomerView

    With cv

       .Name = c.Name
       .AddressLine1 = c.Address.AddressLine1
       .AddressLine2 = c.Address.AddressLine2
       .City = c.Address.City
       .State = c.Address.State
       .ZipCode = c.Address.ZipCode
       ' We aren't doing anything with c.ID, c.CreateDate, c.UpdateDate
       ' or c.TelephoneNumbers

    End With

End For

' Now, bind that List(Of CustomerView) to the DataGridView
DataGridView1.DataSource = list
```

What this essentially does is "flatten" out your object hierarchy, showing only the elements of that hierarchy that you want in the DGV.